# Rails many to many ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a online quiz system in Rails 5.

Here are some models:

`quiz`, `question`, `quiz_question`, `answer`, `category`

`questions (:title, :category_id, type_id)`

`answers (:title, :is_right )`

`quizzes (:title, :category_id, question_count, question_ids)`

The associations are:

```
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, :through => :quiz_questions
  belongs_to :category
end




class QuizQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
  belongs_to :question
end



class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers, inverse_of: :question, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :type
  has_many :quizzes, :through => :quiz_questions
end
```

We get a collection of questions by question's category, when a new quiz generated.

The count of the questions maybe all of the category, or just part of it, such as 100, or 200.

Here is my questions:

1. If it is necessary to create the `QuizQuestion` model to establish the `many-to-many` association?
2. I want to use `question_ids`, the column of `quizzes`, to store the questions that the quiz got from the questions table by the category.
   But there are so many questions, it can't possible to select the needed questions. How to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to take a careful look at the [Active Record Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), particularly the section on [`has_many :through` relationships](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

1. You don't necessarily need a QuizQuestion model, but you probably want one.  The alternative is to just create a join table in your database, and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship instead of the `has_many :through` relationship.  However, `has_many :through` comes with some advantages; most importantly, it allows you to add columns to the association model.  In this case, for example, you're likely to realize down the road that you want to add a `position` field on your QuizQuestion model to allow specific ordering of quiz questions - you couldn't add that with a `has_and_belongs_to_many`.
2. You actually don't need the `question_ids` or `question_count` attributes on your Quiz model.  Your `has_many :through` relationship allows you to do things like this:

   ```
   quiz.questions << a_question    # add a question to the quiz
   quiz.questions -= a_question    # remove a question from the quiz
   quiz.questions.count
   quiz.questions.ids
   ```

   Those last two, in particular, make it unnecessary to have either of those attributes on your quiz model - it's automatically taken care of for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are many valuable points. As you said, I still used `has_many :through` . I got another problem: there many SQL queries like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "questions" INNER JOIN "quiz_questions" ON ...`, when use `quiz.questions.count`

Comment: Are you using it inside a loop?  Because rails should only generate one query each time you call `quiz.questions.count`...